# Trouble passing parameters to a scriptblock

Tags: powershell

I am having alot of difficulty passing parameters to a script block in powershell.

```
    $delScript={del C:\DateResults\* $args[0] $args[1] }
    $result0 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $targetServer.TrimStart("\\") -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock $delScript -ArgumentList @("/q" , "/s")
```

I am starting to lose the plot trying to please the syntax hell of powershell and it's script block. I have researched this problem to death and I cannot even seem to get this basic problem working. I was hoping after spending the better part of 4hrs on this problem someone on SO could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `del` is an alias for `Remove-Item`. From what i can see  [`Remove-Item`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx) only accepts one positional argument which is `-Path`. You are, presumeably, passing 3. What are you trying to pass to the script block?

Comment: I just want to pass some switches to the del command that's all. Probably my naivety thinking it's a batch command. Pardon the ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an issue since you are trying to run a old dos command that PowerShell created an alias for to help ease you into powershell. As mentioned in the comment `del` is an alias for `Remove-Item`. `Remove-Item` only accepts one positional argument which is `-Path`. To allow your script to work as is you should just be able change your `$delScript` to this

```
$delScript={cmd.exe /C del C:\DateResults\* $args[0] $args[1] }
```

Which would run your code the way you would expect. While I was typing this you already figured out the better approach which is to use the native `Remove-Item` and remove your `-ArgumentList` from `Invoke-Command`

```
$delScript={Remove-Item C:\DateResults\* -Recurse -Force}
```

I would also recommend you check `Get-Alias` to see other so you don't get yourself caught again.

Comment: Thanks, your first comment above, is what triggered everything and things started to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was down to my own ignorance and stupidity. Hovering over 'del' in PowerGUI should have told me everything I needed to know.

Below is all I needed in the end.

```
    $delScript={del C:\DateResults\* -Recurse -Force }
$result0 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $targetServer.TrimStart("\\") -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock $delScript
```

Comment: It would have been nice in PS, if the errors told me more about why I was having the problem I was having, misleading me into thinking it's just a syntax issue. Which is what ultimately cost me alot of time.

Comment: When I execute your script I get an error that says `Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/q'`.  Not sure how much more helpful PowerShell could be in this case.  :-)